# flex - How to tell if my component moves in the global coordinate system?

Tags: apache-flex, move, coordinate-systems

I've got a label inside a panel, and I've drawn a line to that label.  So I need to know when the label moves to update the line.  Is there a way to know when the label moves, I can listen for when the label moves inside the panel, but is there a way to know when the panel moves? (which moves the label inside) which might be inside another panel or another panel?
I can set up an eventlistener on the EnterFrame and convert the label origin to localToGlobal and see if it changed, but it seems like overkill...
thanks,

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087885/in-flex-how-can-i-detect-when-a-component-moves

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [move event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#event%3amove) to tell when a Flex Component moves.

It is tough to expand on the answer without more details of your code.  But, I suspect you may be better off drawing the line and positioning the label as part of the Panel's [local co-ordinate system](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=containers_intro_5.html), and then when the Panel moves you won't have to worry about repositioning the label and your line.

You could wrap the label and line in a single component for this purpose. Instead of moving the label specifically; you could move a custom "LabelAndLine" component.

Comment: Hi, my problem is that I have a line from outside the panel pointing to the label inside the panel.  The move event for the label doesn't get fired when the panel moves.  Also if my panel is in a viewport and get's scrolled, the move event doesn't fire.  My goal is to keep the line pointing to the label inside the panel, so I need to know when the label moves to update the line pointing to it.

Comment: That is a lot of good information you should consider adding to the original question.